# VS2015 Formatting code on save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I spent 30 minutes trying to make a GIF capture of this small enough to embed in the question but I couldn't get below 3MB and it became unintelligible, so the full capture is [here](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/Ah2srZm2mvJGzmVDqo).

I have a large ASPX file.  When I click Edit > Advanced > Format document it gives me this section:

```
    </asp:HyperLink></h3>
<asp:UpdatePanel
```

And when I save the document, it reformats to this:

```
    </asp:HyperLink></h3><asp:UpdatePanel ...
```

Honestly both annoy me, but unless I explicitly format I don't get the former.  However *sometimes* when I save, it formats to the latter.  This is just one example, it mangles the file in many places.  Like going from this:

```
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ...
```

To this:

```
</asp:HyperLink></td></tr></table></div></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel></div><asp:UpdatePanel ...ny places.
```

I have ReSharper installed, but I have suspended it for this test to rule it out.

So the question is 2 parts:

1. Why does VS format in 2 different ways, depending on whether it's trigger by a request to format or a save, and
2. How do I disable this format on save?  I can only find options for VSCode, this is VS 2015 Community.

Comment: Do you have any other extensions like the [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015) or [CodeMaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) installed?

Comment: @FlashOver None that I installed explicitly.  However I went through and purged some of the extensions I definitely wasn't using (mostly Azure stuff), and the issue has stopped.  For now.  I have seen it intermittently in the past, it was just reproducible for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Check the other [Visual Studio Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) that you have installed. There might be one (or perhaps even several) which performs custom code formatting on a file save operation.

Comment: The only extensions I've installed explicitly are: Bootstrap Snippet Pack, GitHub Extension for VS, Glyphfriend 2015, .NET Core Tools, BitBucket VS Extension and VS Installer Projects.  Nothing that should be doing formatting.  As per my comment on the question above, I uninstalled a bunch of junk extensions and for now the issue has stopped.  However it has always been intermittent, and I doubt any of those (Azure) extensions were doing formatting.